# Dexguard 7.3.01 incompatible with gradle 2.3.0

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, dexguard

I'm working in a project that uses Dexguard, but when I try update gradle to version 2.3.0, I get the following error message on sync:

> Error:No such property: sdkHandler for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin

Settings:

> Dexguard version 7.3.01
>
> com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0
>
> gradle distribution3.3
>
> Android Studio 2.3

P.S: On gradle 2.2.0 I don't have this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chris try to do the following things after updating ur AS to 2.4...

ProjectStructure->Project->Change Android Plugin Version to 2.2.0.

Another option would be if u follow this editing your Project's build.gradle file(NOT module's build.gradle file) and change to following statement to this way:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

You can also try to change your Sdk's path through your build.gradle file here:

```
android{
    System.out.printf("ndkDirectory: %s                    \n", ndkDirectory);
 }
```

Hope it works!

Comment: But I need update gradle to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0, not no 2.2.0.

Comment: For me its a big problem too. Gradle 4.0 not supported 2.2.x of android plugin...